# Creating a bookmarklet that doesn't get blocked

Tags: javascript, popup, bookmarklet

**Goal:** To create a bookmarklet that calls a remote javascript file that opens a popup window. The popup window is functionally similar to what Delicious's bookmarklet does.

**Background:** Currently, I'm using window.open within this javascript file, however the popup is getting blocked by pretty much every major browser.

The alternative solution to this is very similar to the way Delicious wrote their bookmarklet - calling window.open through a javascript query within the bookmarklet itself. However, I need the ability to modify the other contents of my javascript file in the future without requiring users to continually grab newest releases of the bookmarklet.

**What I've determined to be happening:** Since the window.open call is not occurring *directly* as a result of a click by the user, the browser feels this is something that should be blocked. Here's [a source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537632(VS.85).aspx) on this.

[This](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/) is the tutorial I referenced most recently in creating the call to the remote js file.

Here is a basic example of what my code is doing; the window.open/popup portion is the only significant part I'm including as it's the only part I feel is causing the complication:

Example of the remote javascript file:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.onload=runthis;
    jQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js';
    document.body.appendChild(jQ);
} else {
    runthis();
}

function runthis() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'a title',
       'location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550');
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help as this has been stumping me for a while!

Comment: If you could do this, from an external included file, why couldn't every spammer and intrusive advertiser do the same?  If you think about the abuses this would offer, it's pretty easy to see why it's actively blocked by every browser.

Comment: Eh, this is a bookmarklet, the user has to actively click it and bookmarklets need user interaction to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach that looks better and side-steps the blocking issue is to have the bookmarklet insert an iframe in the page the user is currently viewing. Ended up taking this approach back when I asked this question. Worked out fine.